# Is it possible to set up an emulator with these specific requirements?

Tags: android-emulator

At work we've been given an opportunity to work with some hardware running a (semi) custom Android build. The long and short of it is the app we make needs to fit certain criteria.

Uses TEGRA2, Android 4.0.3 Level 15, and supporting 1366 x 768 res with 90px system bar.

Can I make an emulator to simulate all these? The API level is obviously easy to set up, and the custom resolution, however, I can't see any options to do with tegra2.

As a note they do have a SDK available for this, which may include an emulator, but we don't have a copy yet so I'm looking for a quick temporary workaround until we get a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Android emulator doesn't emulate specific SoCs such as Tegra 2, and it doesn't support Nvidia's instruction set extensions.

Comment: Ahh okay, so the closest I can get is the screen res and API version?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: That is, unless Nvidia has something more specific. They can implement Tegra 2, and almost certainly have an emulator they use in-house to test their own software.

Comment: Well to be honest I don't think the Tegra 2 is going to affect our app, it wont be doing anything graphic heavy, mostly just displaying data. I'll see what the SDK has when we get it, and if that doesn't come with an emulator I'll dummy up the closest I can get.